# Do Fourier Transforms work with periodic monotonically increasing functions?

Tags: fourier-transform, step-function

When I say "work", I mean will a clear frequency be detected? And by "periodic monotonically increasing functions", I mean functions such as the [stair case function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StaircaseFunction.html).

Comment: Any function with step-discontinouities will have nasty convergence properties for the Fourier transform as it only converges on average and not point-wise.

Comment: You can read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon

Comment: Given a "periodic monotonically increasing" function, you don't need Fourier transform to detect its period.

Comment: Would you make precise what you mean by "Fourier transform", please? What most people know under that name simply doesn't exist for your staircase function.

Comment: hah nice intro to number theoretic transform by the way :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A frequency can be detected, but it's not so clear..

[image]
[image]

3 staircases of 5 steps, every 15th frequency is 0. the first non-zero frequency is 3 and $15/3 = 5$. Any curious student can probably prove the general case. Some hints on that endeavor could be that

1. the Fourier transform is linear.
2. the Fourier transform of a box function is a sinc and
3. the convolution theorem.